# What is the difference between performing upsampling together with strided transpose convolution and transpose convolution with stride 1 only?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, convolution, deconvolution

I noticed in a number of places that people use something like this, usually in fully convolutional networks, autoencoders, and similar:

```
model.add(UpSampling2D(size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(kernel_size=k, padding='same', strides=(1,1))
```

I am wondering what is the difference between that and simply:

```
model.add(Conv2DTranspose(kernel_size=k, padding='same', strides=(2,2))
```

Links towards any papers that explain this difference are welcome.

Comment: here is also explanation of it https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

[Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/6107/what-are-deconvolutional-layers) and [here](https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic) you can find a really nice explanation of how *transposed convolutions* work. To sum up both of these approaches:

1. In your first approach, you are first upsampling your feature map:

   ```
   [[1, 2], [3, 4]] -> [[1, 1, 2, 2], [1, 1, 2, 2], [3, 3, 4, 4], [3, 3, 4, 4]]
   ```

   and then you apply a classical convolution (as `Conv2DTranspose` with `stride=1` and `padding='same'` is equivalent to `Conv2D`).
2. In your second approach you are first *un(max)pooling* your feature map:

   ```
   [[1, 2], [3, 4]] -> [[1, 0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [3, 0, 4, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
   ```

   and then apply a classical convolution with `filter_size`, filters`, etc.

   [image]

Fun fact is that - although these approaches are different they share something in common. Transpose convolution is meant to be the approximation of gradient of convolution, so the first approach is approximating `sum pooling` whereas second `max pooling` gradient. This makes the first results to produce slightly smoother results.

Other reasons why you might see the first approach are:

- `Conv2DTranspose` (and its equivalents) are relatively new in `keras` so the only way to perform learnable upsampling was using `Upsample2D`,
- Author of `keras` - Francois Chollet used this approach in [one](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) of his tutorials,
- In the past equivalents of transpose, convolution seemed to work awful in `keras` due to some `API` inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out a couple of things that you mentioned. `Upsample2D` is not a learnable layer since There is literally 0 parameter.

Also, we can not justify the reason why we might want to use the first approach **because** Francoise Chollet introduced the usage in his example.